# SQL Server Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hello I have done the following query below:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TestData]
SET Duplicate = 'Duplicate within'
WHERE exists 
(SELECT telephone, COUNT(telephone)
FROM [dbo].[TestData]
GROUP BY telephone
HAVING (COUNT (telephone)>1))
```

In that table there are actually 9 duplicate telephone records.

The query is stamping the entire duplicate column as 'Duplicate within' instead of the 9 records.

The next following query I have also developed which will unstamp the 18 duplicate records to 9.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TestData]
SET Duplicate = 'NO'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM [dbo].[TestData] GROUP BY telephone)
```

This query is not working neither could anyone please guide me on where I am going wrong!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using where exists, but it's easier to write/read this way and the performance difference is most likely minimal.

```
update TestData set 
    Duplicate = 'Duplicate within'
where 
    Telephone in (
        select Telephone 
        from TestData 
        group by Telephone 
        having count(*) > 1
    )
```

To leave the first record with each telephone number alone and mark only the subsequent records with the same telephone number, use a cte as follows:

```
;with NumberedDupes as (
    select
        Telephone,
        Duplicate,
        row_number() over (partition by Telephone order by Telephone) seq
    from TestData
)
update NumberedDupes set Duplicate = 'Duplicate within' where seq > 1
```

Comment: If I wanted to just unstamp the duplicates as there is 18 how do I just unstamp back to 9?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unstamp". Do you want to delete duplicate records? Or do you want to only mark one of each as duplicate?

Comment: I want to only mark one of each duplicate as the query above has marked 18 above. I would like it to mark 9.

Comment: +1. I think the 2nd query, the `CTE` is what O.P. is looking for, but having a hard time conveying it in his/her question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `EXISTS` query isn't filtered. It needs to be filtered by each phone #:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TestData]
SET Duplicate = 'Duplicate within'
FROM [TestData] t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT telephone, COUNT(telephone)
    FROM [dbo].[TestData]
    WHERE telephone = t.telephone
    GROUP BY telephone
    HAVING (COUNT (telephone)>1))
)
```

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka, well the SQL you posted isn't the SQL I provided - you posted (in your comment) the very same SQL you posted in your question. It's not surprising that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the type error that works thank you very much!. Will the next query be in full working format to unstamp 18 to 9?

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka, as long as you follow the same pattern it will work fine. You have to add the `FROM` and the filtering (to the `EXISTS` query).

Comment: how come there is a t near FROM [TestData] and   t.telephone?

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka, the `FROM [TestData]` is indicating that you want to evaluate each row before updating it and you want those evaluations to come from `[TestData]`, then in the `EXISTS` query we use that table to filter it properly. We only want to mark it as a duplicate **if** the row we are on has more just like it.

Comment: If I wanted to just unstamp the duplicates as there is 18 how do I just unstamp back to 9?

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka: I'm not sure what you're saying, but I believe you need to post that as another question. That question should include the SQL you **did execute,** the table values now, and what table values you want. At this point it's getting too difficult to assist any further without a better picture.

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka The `t` following the `[TestData]` table name is an alias. So instead of writing `[TestData]` everywhere in the query, you can use `t` and it will resolve to the same table name. For example: `WHERE telephone = t.telephone`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the duplicates, you need to look at one of the two records as demonstrated by the sub select below. The EXISTS will actually make you update both rows since that is what you are testing.

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[TestData]
    SET Duplicate = 'Duplicate within'
    WHERE Id IN  
    (SELECT MAX(Id)
    FROM [dbo].[TestData]
    GROUP BY telephone
    HAVING (COUNT (telephone)>1))
```

Comment: If I wanted to just unstamp the duplicates as there is 18 how do I just unstamp back to 9?

Comment: My query should only update the 9 duplicate rows, using the last id inserted as the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much! so the first two lines are updating and setting. What is the Max(Id) bit doing? I am trying to understand as well :) I am new to SQL

Comment: The MAX(Id) is finding the highest value in the Id field. This, combined with the GROUP BY and the HAVING, finds the highest Id possible for all rows with the same "telephone" value.