# Duplicate Mail Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having trouble recovering records with duplicate addresses. Meaning there can be records with the same postcode but different first line of address. The query I have developed stamps all records with the same postcode as duplicates even if the first line of address is different and the first name.

Below is the query I have developed to locate duplicates then unstamp them:

```
update DATA set                                 
    Duplicate = 'DuplicateWithinItself'
where 
    Postcode in (
        select Postcode
        from  DATA
        group by FirstName, Address1, Postcode, Postcode
        having count(*) > '1'
    )

GO

UPDATE Data                                                 
SET Duplicate = 'NO'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN (ID) FROM Data GROUP BY Postcode)
```

Can someone please help me define records that are actually duplicates with the same first name and same first line of address (address 1) and postcode. Or even if it is the same first line of address and postcode that is classed as a duplicate. Then I would like to unstamp one version of the duplicate records.

Comment: Did you asked the same quoestion [SQL Server Duplicate Records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682006/sql-server-duplicate-records) before?? Seems this one is a duplicate then!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear what your current query does, but

```
;with Cte_Temp as (Select FirstName, Address1,Postcode, Duplicate ,PostcodeCount =ROW_NUMBER()
                over(PARTITION By Postcode  Order By Postcode)
                From DATA)
```

--You can get the duplicates by

```
   Select *
   From Cte_Temp 
   Where PostcodeCount >1
```

--You can do update as well
e.g.

```
   Update Cte_Temp 
   Duplicate ='xxx'
   Where PostcodeCount >1
```

Comment: Thank you would the query listed above select records with the same firstname address1 and postcode?

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka:At the moment it is only by postcode. Do you need to get the duplicate by combination of firstname address1 and postcode??